# cv2.findContours does not find white rectangles on a black background

Tags: python, opencv

I am an experienced programmer but with limited Python and OpenCV experience. I am working to crop movie frames, trying to use the visible perforations and edge of the film as references. Attached are a single frame (original 1920 x 1080) and a mask derived from that frame being passed to findcountours in the code below. FindContours finds 3 contours but only the largest (right frame boundary) is correct, the other two (drive perforations) are not detected properly. Would one of you kind people tell me what I'm doing wrong and point me in the direction of goodness?

I am using Python 3.8 with the associated version of cv2.

Here is a [sample frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKRaA.png) and the [mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui6yh.png) derived using the code below.

Thank You

Chris

```
for file in args.files:

idx += 1

if os.path.isfile(file):

    # load the input image (whose path was supplied via command line
    # argument) and display the image to our screen
    image = cv2.imread(file)

    if image is None:
        print('Could not open or find the image: ', args["image"])
        fileinput.close()
        exit(0)

    image_clone = image.copy()
    image_height = image.shape[0]
    image_width = image.shape[1]



    """
    Threshold image
    """

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    #
    # # define range of white color in HSV
    # # change it according to your need !
    lower_white = np.array([0, 0, 235], dtype=np.uint8)
    upper_white = np.array([0, 0, 255], dtype=np.uint8)
    #
    # Threshold the HSV image to get only white colors
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white)

    mask = cv2.copyMakeBorder(mask, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0, 0, 0])

    # I have seen some spurious pixels so I filter
    
    se1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5, 5))
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, se1, iterations = 5)

    # Make sure I get rid of noise
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (5, 5), 0)

    cny = cv2.Canny(mask.copy(), 255/3, 255)

    mask = cv2.bitwise_xor(mask, cny)

    cv2.imwrite(os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '_mask_' + str(idx) + '.tif', mask)

    dsize = (int(mask.shape[1] * (50 / 100)), int(mask.shape[0] * (50 / 100)))
    # # # # # #
    cv2.imshow("Mask Image", cv2.resize(mask.copy(), dsize))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyWindow("Mask Image")

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
    #
    new_image = np.zeros((mask.shape[0], mask.shape[1]), np.uint8) * 0
    #
    cv2.drawContours(new_image, [max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)], -1, 255, thickness=-1)

    dsize = (int(new_image.shape[1] * (50 / 100)), int(new_image.shape[0] * (50 / 100)))
    # # # # # # #
    cv2.imshow("Mask Image", cv2.resize(new_image.copy(), dsize))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyWindow("Mask Image")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the arguments to the function `drawContours`. The second argument contains the `contours` that should be drawn, but you seem to be filtering the smaller contours and just storing/drawing the biggest one, which in this case, is the contour to the right of the frame. Do not filter your `contours`. Try computing them instead like this:

```
# Find the contours on the mask image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Draw the contours on the mask image:
cv2.drawContours(maskCopy, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

Note that the third argument is `-1`, this means, draw all the contours found. This is what you get:

[image]

Additionally, you might want to convert these contours into `bounding rectangles` so you can crop easily your region of interest. This is how you convert the contours to a `4-vertex polygon`:

```
contoursPoly = [None] * len(contours)
boundRect = []

# Contour to Bounding Rects:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
   # Approximate each contour to a bonding rectangle:
   contoursPoly[i] = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
   # Append each bounding rect to the list:
   boundRect.append(cv2.boundingRect(contours_poly[i]))

# Draw the Bounding Rects:
rectColor = (0, 255, 0)
for i in range(len(boundRect)):    
    cv2.rectangle(maskCopy, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])),
              (int(boundRect[i][0] + boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1] + boundRect[i][3])), rectColor, 5)
```

Notice now how the contours are approximated as rectangles:

[image]

Now, you use some `morphology` to get a clean binary mask. That's actually pretty good, but the morphological operations distort a little bit the mask’s blobs, introducing location offsets. Check out the bounding rectangles overlaid into the original image:

[image]

See the location offsets? You could try to apply extra `morphology` to restore the blobs' original positions.

**1st Alternative:**

Do not use morphology and consider only the **outer contours**. Outer contours are parent contours that don’t have child (inner) contours. That will filter out any possible noise you could have:

```
# BGR to HSV conversion:
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage.copy(), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# HSV Range definition:
lower_white = np.array([0, 0, 235], dtype=np.uint8)
upper_white = np.array([0, 0, 255], dtype=np.uint8)

# Get the HSV mask:
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white)

# Find the big contours/blobs on the filtered image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contoursPoly = [None] * len(contours)
boundRect = []

# Alright, just look for the outer bounding boxes:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    if hierarchy[0][i][3] == -1:
        contoursPoly[i] = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
        boundRect.append(cv2.boundingRect(contoursPoly[i]))

# Draw the bounding boxes on the (copied) input image:
for i in range(len(boundRect)):
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    cv2.rectangle(inputCopy, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])),
              (int(boundRect[i][0] + boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1] + boundRect[i][3])), color, 5)
```

You get this:

[image]

**2nd Alternative:**

Use the [reduce](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4b78072a303f29d9031d56e5638da78e) function to reduce the binary mask to a `1 x columns` *matrix*, detect contours and extract the inner coordinates to crop the frame:

```
# Reduce matrix to a 1 row x n columns matrix:
reducedMask = cv2.reduce(mask, 0, cv2.REDUCE_MAX)
```

The reduce function will create a `1 x columns` matrix (actually a *vector*) that will contain the `MAX` value of all the columns. The `MAX` value (`255`) in the binary masks corresponds to the location of the blobs of interest, thus, reducing the image to this new mask:

[image]

The idea now is to get the coordinates of the two white sections. This can be achieved by more than one method. Let's stick to finding contours for now:

```
# Find the big contours/blobs on the filtered image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(reducedMask, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

contoursPoly = [None] * len(contours)
boundRect = []

# Alright, just look for the outer bounding boxes:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    if hierarchy[0][i][3] == -1:
        contoursPoly[i] = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
        boundRect.append(cv2.boundingRect(contoursPoly[i]))
```

The contours obtained so far describe the two white sections. We need the inner coordinates of these lines. Let's `sort` the bonded rectangle list from smallest to largest. The list is a `tuple`, and the first element of each `tuple` is the `top left` (or horizontal) coordinate, so we have the first white section after ordering the list:

```
# Sort rects from smallets to largest:
sortedRectangles = sorted(boundRect, key = lambda topLeft: topLeft[0])

# Set Top Left crop coordinate:
startX = sortedRectangles[0][0] + sortedRectangles[0][2]

# Set Lower Right crop coordinate:
endX = sortedRectangles[1][0]
```

Now, just crop the image using this info:

```
# Crop the roi:
imageSize = inputCopy.shape
imageHeight = imageSize[0]
croppedImg = inputCopy[0:0+imageHeight, startX:endX]
```

And you get the final cropped image:

[image]

Comment: Wow. I've been beating my head against that wall for 24 hours and didn't recognize the problem was in the print rather than the find. You are a gentleperson and scholar. I need to review the description of the contour structure more closely. Thank you and thumbs up.

Comment: @user2488847 No problem! Glad I could help.